# How to print split columns?

Tags: vba

Assume starting is 1 and stopping is 10. I want to print 1 to 5 in column Number then 6 - 10 in another column Number.

Can I do this in single loop?  or I have to do in another loop?
Also I cannot figure out how to start at second column which `{1, -10}`

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}", "Number")

    Dim split = (starting + stopping) / 2

    For A = starting To split
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}", A)
    Next
```

**UPDATE** - expected result

```
Number Number
1      6
2      7
3      8
4      9
5      10
```

**UPDATE 2** - make them align
Instead of using Space(), any other solution we can make them same width and align them in center column
[image]

Comment: `vba` or `vb.net`? Those are different frameworks. Can you show result what you expecting?

Comment: question updated @Fabio

Comment: Use `vbTab` constant: `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", column1Value, vbTab, column2Value)`

Comment: @Fabio yup i figured it out.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like this, using a single loop:

```
Sub TwoColumns(ByVal starting as Integer,ByVal stopping as Integer)
  Dim split As Integer,i As Integer
  split = (starting + stopping) / 2
  For i=starting  to split
    Debug.Print (i) & Space(5) &  (i+split-starting)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but 1 more question.  can we use other than Space()?  
because they don't print in same width. Check my updated picture.

Comment: and align them in center column as well

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you

Comment: This solution will print extra row (with number 11) and number 6 will be printed twice

Comment: @Fabio  maybe, but it is ok because I use (i - starting + split + 1)

Answer (score 0):

When making strings align on console output, I usually use a function with Space Padding (either to left or right), very useful when you want formatted output.

Below will fit any number of columns to split the arrays you have (more generic as you can set how many columns to split into). If you are just want to display an array in a table look, use **`TabulateArray(...)`**.

```
Sub DisplayTuplesTest()
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
    arr2 = Array(1.61, 3.22, 4.83, 6.44, 8.05, 9.66, 11.27, 12.88, 14.49, 16.1, 17.71, 19.32, 20.93, 22.54, 24.15, 25.76, 27.37, 28.98, 30.59, 32.2)
    Call DisplayTuples(arr1, arr2, 2)
    Call TabulateArray(arr2, 2)
End Sub

Sub DisplayTuples(Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant, iCols As Integer)
    Dim Count1 As Integer, Count2 As Integer ' Counts # of items in the array
    Dim Max1 As Integer, Max2 As Integer ' Tracks the max length of values
    Dim n As Integer, oTmp As Variant ' Temporary variables
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, rows As Integer, sTxt As String ' For displaying results

    Count1 = UBound(Array1)
    Count2 = UBound(Array2)
    If Count1 <> Count2 Then
        Debug.Print "Arrays are not same dimension!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Max length of Array1
    Max1 = 0
    For Each oTmp In Array1
        n = Len(CStr(oTmp))
        If Max1 < n Then Max1 = n
    Next

    ' Max length of Array2
    Max2 = 0
    For Each oTmp In Array2
        n = Len(CStr(oTmp))
        If Max2 < n Then Max2 = n
    Next

    ' Lets say we want 4 spaces from longest value of Array1 value before showing Array2 value
    Max1 = Max1 + 4
    ' Lets say we want 8 spaces from longest value of Array2 value before showing Array1 value on next column
    Max2 = Max2 + 8

    ' Rows required to display arrays into iCols columns
    rows = Count1 \ iCols
    If rows * iCols < Count1 Then rows = rows + 1 ' If an extra rows is required

    ' Display in a table like format, with spliting into iCols columns
    For r = 0 To rows - 1
        sTxt = ""
        For c = 0 To iCols - 1
            n = r + c * rows ' calculates the n'th index to display
            If n > Count1 Then Exit For
            sTxt = sTxt & SpacePadding_R(Array1(n), Max1) & SpacePadding_R(Array2(n), Max2)
        Next
        Debug.Print sTxt
    Next
End Sub

Sub TabulateArray(Array1 As Variant, iCols As Integer)
    Dim Count1 As Integer ' Counts # of items in the array
    Dim Max1 As Integer, Max2 As Integer ' Tracks the max length of values
    Dim n As Integer, oTmp As Variant ' Temporary variables
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, rows As Integer, sTxt As String ' For displaying results

    Count1 = UBound(Array1)

    ' Max length of n'th index
    Max1 = Len(CStr(Count1 + 1))

    ' Lets say we want 3 spaces from max count of Array1 value before showing the Array1 value
    Max1 = Max1 + 4
    ' Lets say we want 8 spaces from longest value of Array1 value before next column
    Max2 = Max2 + 8

    ' Rows required to display arrays into iCols columns
    rows = Count1 \ iCols
    If rows * iCols < Count1 Then rows = rows + 1 ' If an extra rows is required

    ' Display in a table like format, with spliting into iCols columns
    For r = 0 To rows - 1
        sTxt = ""
        For c = 0 To iCols - 1
            n = r + c * rows ' calculates the n'th index to display
            If n > Count1 Then Exit For
            sTxt = sTxt & SpacePadding_R(n + 1, Max1) & SpacePadding_R(Array1(n), Max2)
        Next
        Debug.Print sTxt
    Next
End Sub

Function SpacePadding_R(oValue As Variant, iMaxLen As Integer) As String
    Dim sOutput As String, iLen As Integer
    sOutput = CStr(oValue)
    iLen = Len(sOutput)
    If iLen < iMaxLen Then
        ' Pad spaces at the end of the input (Right side)
        sOutput = sOutput & String(iMaxLen - iLen, " ")
    Else
        ' Optional if you want to restrict this
        sOutput = Left(sOutput, iMaxLen)
    End If
    SpacePadding_R = sOutput
End Function
```

Output with sample arrays (highlighted to show you the spaces added):
[image: Sample Output]